# String input function using dynamic memory allocation breaks after random amount of characters

Tags: c, string, memory-management, malloc, realloc

I'm terrible at life, so it's possible my function itself is just broken beyond repair. The function takes user input using getchar(), dynamically reallocates memory per-character with realloc() (and I'm sure that's probably innefficient as hell but I'm not sure how else to keep it memory efficient) and returns a full string as a char pointer. Here's the code:

```
char *get_string_input(){
    char c, *str = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    // allocate initial space for a single character
    str = malloc(sizeof(char));

    while(c != '\n' && c != EOF){
        c = getchar();
        str[i++] = c;

        // reallocate with space for +1 additional character
        str = realloc(str, i * sizeof(char));
    }

    str[i] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

If a certain amount of characters are entered (between 7 - 9 usually) the program will crash. I have no idea where the issue lies, and it's happening with pretty much anything I try and type.

Help much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It is necessary to secure space including null-terminator. Also `char c` --> `int c` for compare with EOF

Comment: There are a few issues with this program. The first is that getchar() returns an int, not a char. The second is that realloc() may fail and return NULL thereby overriding str. However, the real issue is that you should be calling realloc() with (i+1)*sizeof(char)

Comment: @levengli ah, so I'm calling it with one less than I'm supposed to be each time? I thought me incrementing i in str[i++] = c; was fixing that, but I probably misread my own code and/or don't understand realloc properly. Thank you for the other tips as well.

Comment: Indeed you are @Sato. Fix and try running again

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, the code takes care of allocating space for the null terminator

Comment: @levengli no. _reallocate with space for +1 additional character_ `realloc(str, i * sizeof(char))`

Comment: True, and after the last character is read one more byte will be allocated

Comment: I believe there should still be room for the null character no matter what.